# Active Directory returns only 1000 records(PHP)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have 61000 records that i have to fetch but i am able to retrieve only 1000 records. I have tried Zend Pagination for retrieving the data, but that did not work.

Can any one help me out.

Comment: Please provide the code you have used to attempt to achieve this, and any errors, or issues you feel might be causing it.

Comment: Without your code, it's virtually impossible to help you

Comment: I think default MaxPageSize in AD is set to 1000. Check if you can change it for your version.

Answer (score 2):

This limit is set by AD's `MaxPageSize` and it defaults to 1000, so it's a normal situation.

> [MaxPageSize](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315071/how-to-view-and-set-ldap-policy-in-active-directory-by-using-ntdsutil) - This value controls the maximum number of objects that
>   are returned in a single search result, independent of how large each
>   returned object is. To perform a search where the result might exceed
>   this number of objects, the client must specify the paged search
>   control. This is to group the returned results in groups that are no
>   larger than the MaxPageSize value. To summarize, MaxPageSize controls
>   the number of objects that are returned in a single search result.

You can't change this limit from the client side, but you can still overcome paginated results using [LDAP pagination control](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php).

Note that pagination control is a LDAPv3 protocol feature so don't forget to set the option :

```
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

See also [Simple Paged Results Control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control).